# Positioning an image top right corner using css

Tags: css

I am trying to position an image to the top right of my website. It previews perfectly in chrome and IE, but when i upload it, it doesnt hover over the site, it pushes everything down.

This is my css:

```
.c3 a img {
position: fixed;
top:0;
right:0;
z-index:10;
```

}

Website: futsocusa.net

Answer (score 3):

It looks fine to me. Have you tried ctrl+f5 to clear your cache?

Comment: ohh wow, completely forgot about that xD. all fixed. thank you